# Generate and Dispose before using?

Tags: c#, dispose

Today my intstructor, where I'm intern, said I should use

```
    HImage hi = null;

    HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObject(out hi);
    hi.Dispose();

    hi = f.GrabImageAsync(-1.0);
```

Instead of

```
    HImage hi = null;

    hi = f.GrabImageAsync(-1.0);
```

Prototypes of used functions as follows

```
    void HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObj(out HObject emptyObject);
    HImage HFramegrabber.GrabImageAsync(double maxDelay);
```

I respect my instructor ,but I don't see any meaningful explanation at creating and disposing an object before calling `hi = f.GrabImageAsync(-1.0);` as that functions returns an instance of that object and therefore no need for Generating and Disposing object first, at least in my opinion.

So anyone can clarify if it is really needed or not. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks utterly pointless. I can think of some reasons why you would dispose an object before using it in some ways (e.g. disposing a memory stream before grabbing the buffer), but not creating, disposing, wiping like this. Maybe though there is some side-effect in this case. Why did your instructor say it should be done?

Comment: "Those who can, do; those who can't, teach."

Comment: If this is all of your code, you are right, it's totally pointless to create and dispose an object that way. But it can depend on the context. If there happens more between the declaration and the `Dispose ` (maybe even inside the `GenEmptyObject` function, it might be nessecary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. Generally there is no use in creating and immediately disposing a variable.

As far as we can see from the code, `HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObject` doesn't interact with your `f` variable, so there would be no meaning in calling that method.

Also, there is no point in setting `HImage hi` to `null`, since that is probably the default already and it is set using the `out` parameter.

So my bet would be on:

```
HImage hi = f.GrabImageAsync(-1.0);
```

Comment: The only reason I can see why this makes sense is if there is some "spooky action at a distance" when calling `HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObject`. This to me is in fact more reason to ignore your instructor, as that is very magical programming, and encourages siloing of knowledge.

Comment: @Aron though sometimes the spooky action effects are something we have to deal with. The flaw in the instruction in that case is that if there's something weird you have to deal with, then you have to learn what that weird thing is, or you've no hope of doing anything beyond cargo-cult programming. (Indeed, the code is definitely wrong; code that does something weird to deal with something weird should have the weirdness pointed out in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time `Dispose()` is called to release all managed resources that no longer in need. So let's assume that `HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObject(out hi)` method opens FileStream and saves reference to some field in new HImage instance. Later in code you would like to do other operation with this HImage instance and no longer need this FileStream or any other resources. It's a good moment to call `hi.Dispose()` that closes it before you proceed with doing anything else. But in any other case your instructor is misleading you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few classes in WinForms which have multiple purposes, some of which require resources and some of which don't.  The one I'm most familiar with is `Font`.  A `Font` instance encapsulates a combination of font settings as well as a GDI handle to a GDI font resource.  The `Font` property setter of most WinForms controls will cause the controls to copy of the settings from the passed-in font object and store a copy of the passed in `Font` reference so that it may be returned by a call to the property getter, but will not cause the controls to actually use the passed-in font for drawing.  Since the settings can be read from a `Font` object even after is is disposed, it is in fact possible to create and dispose `Font` objects when setting controls' `Font` properties; in some cases it may arguably be a reasonable least-of-evils approach:

1. If `Font` objects are created and abandoned without disposal, that will usually not cause too much of a GDI resource drain, but such wishful thinking doesn't represent good design.
2. A policy of calling `Dispose` on a control's old value of `Font` before setting a new value will require that every control own its own separate `Font` object, which will then encapsulate a resource the control will never use.  The one advantage is that code which reads a control's `Font` property will be able to draw using that `Font` object directly.
3. Having controls hold references to font objects that are already disposed will make it possible for multiple controls to safely share the same font object, and will consume fewer GDI resources than either of the other approaches.  The one limitation is that any code which reads a control's `Font` property and wants to draw with that font will have to use it to construct a new `Font` object for the purpose (and probably dispose of it after use).

IMHO, the fact that disposing `Font` objects immediately on creation is a useful pattern suggests that the Framework should have included separate types for the purposes of *describing* fonts (the purpose of a control's `Font` property) and encapsulating GDI font objects (the purpose of the `Font` parameter to string-drawing methods).  If the latter type had included `Dispose` and the former type not, there would have been no question about how to use each.  Since the `Font` type exists, however, along with code that uses it for those disjoint purposes, the eager-dispose pattern may be a reasonable least-of-evils approach.

I'm not sure that approach represents what's going on in your instructor's example since I'm not familiar with the types involved.  It may be that the object returned by `GenEmptyObject` doesn't actually allocate any resources and its `Dispose` method does nothing (and stating that the particular object may be safely abandoned may be better than calling `Dispose` prematurely) but if the object acquires resources which won't be needed for its intended use, early disposal might possibly be appropriate *if commented*.